# sql code to compare previous row in a series

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

So I have a table that has an ArticleID (GUID), RevisionNumber (integer), and StatusCode (text).
An Article can have any number of revisions but each time a new revision is created, the StatusCode of the previous revision should be "Revised" and the newest revision's StatusCode could be "Active" or "Draft" or "Canceled".  However the data is messed up and I need to identify which records (out of 100's of thousands) do not have the correct status.
Sample data:

```
Article ID     RevisionNumber     StatusCode
==========     ==============     ==========
xx-xxxx-xx            7             Active
xx-xxxx-xx            6            Revised
xx-xxxx-xx            5             Active
xx-xxxx-xx            4              Draft
xx-xxxx-xx            3            Revised
xx-xxxx-xx            2             Active
xx-xxxx-xx            1            Revised
xx-xxxx-xx            0            Revised
xx-yyyy-yy            1             Active
xx-yyyy-yy            0             Active
```

In the above scenario, I would need to know that xx-xxxx-xx Revision 5, 4, and 2 are not the proper status and xx-yyyy-yy Revision 0 is incorrect.  How could I get this information from a sql query using sql server 2012?

Comment: Have a look at `lag` and `lead` (these were introduced for SQL server 2012 I believe).

Comment: I think a left join is easier than lead and lag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify any revisions that are not "Revised" if there is a higher number revision.

Then it seems just a matter of knowing what the latest revision is.
A `MAX` `OVER` can do that.

```
SELECT ArticleID, RevisionNumber, StatusCode
FROM
(
    SELECT ArticleID, RevisionNumber, StatusCode
    , MAX(RevisionNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY ArticleID) AS MaxRevisionNumber
    FROM YourTable
) q
WHERE (RevisionNumber < MaxRevisionNumber AND StatusCode != 'Revised')
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough.  Anything other than the latest revision should have a status of "Revised".  The most current revision could be "Active", "Draft", or "Canceled".  Revision 0 could be any status if there are no other revisions.  I need to identify any revisions on the list that are not "Revised" if there is a higher number revision.  I hope that helps clarify.

Comment: @W.D.K. Good that you found it. Well, based on your comment, the WHERE clause could be simplified.

Comment: Yes, I did make a little modification to it because I wasn't clear, but you got me where I needed to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a left join -- for each record we look for one with a greater revision -- like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_you_did_not_name base
LEFT JOIN table_you_did_not_name next ON base.ArticleID = next.ArticleID and base.revisionnumber = next.revisionnumber + 1
WHERE status <> 'Revised' and next.ArticleID is not null
```

Comment: @W.D. K.  See the update -- this will get you the correct results and shows you how joins works.  Might be faster too depending on your data and other factors